# repetition of the compounds in the loop python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Good day friends!
Tell me please, I have the following code:

```
all_users = UserProfile.objects.all()
for s,usera in enumerate(all_users):
             name = usera.nickname
             name_id = usera.id
             print(s)
             if int(s) <= 50:
                 print('1_iterator')
                 r = api.request(example)
             elif int(s) <= 100:
                 r = api2.request(example)
             elif #a total of seven compounds, api3,api4,api5,api6,api7
             try:

                for item in r.get_iterator():
                #then loop adds data to the database
```

how do I get a cycle every 50 iterations connect to the new api, and if he reaches seven then again from the beginning, and so has not yet come to an end user in the database?

Advance thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up an `itertools.cycle`.

```
apis = itertools.cycle([api1, api2, api3, api4, api5, api6, api7])
for s,usera in enumerate(all_users):
         if (s % 50) == 0:
             current_api = apis.next()
         name = usera.nickname
         name_id = usera.id
         print(s)
         current_api.request(example)
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks,after launch issues

AttributeError: 'itertools.cycle' object has no attribute 'next'.

have the meaning API api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

Comment: changed to current_api = apis.__next__() earned

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you were in python3. It's `next` in python 2, `__next__` in python 3.